# Using link_to with embedded HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap stuff and I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="btn" href="<%= user_path(@user) %>"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Do it@</a>
```

What's the best way to do this in Rails? I'd like to use `<%= link_to 'Do it', user_path(@user) %>` but the `<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>` is throwing me off?

Answer (score 274):

Two ways. Either:

```
<%= link_to user_path(@user) do %>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Do it@
<% end %>
```

Or:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Do it@'.html_safe, user_path(@user) %>
```

Comment: Maybe missing '.html_safe' after the string for the icon in the second example?

Comment: I did not know that you can pass a block to `link_to` - thanks for teaching me!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same need recently.  Try this:

`<%= link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Do it'.html_safe, user_path(@user) %>`

Answer (score 11):

You have also the possibility to create an helper method like below:

```
def link_fa_to(icon_name, text, link)
  link_to content_tag(:i, text, :class => "fa fa-#{icon_name}"), link
end
```

Adapt the classes to your needs.

Answer (score 9):

In normal HTML we do,

```
<a href="register.html"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Register</a>
```

In Ruby On Rails:

```
<%= link_to routeName_path do %>
  <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Link Name
<% end %>

<%= link_to register_path do %>
   <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Register
<% end %>
```

[image: This is My Output]

Answer (score 8):

If you want a link in rails that uses that same icon class from twitter bootstrap all you need to do is something like this.

```
<%= link_to "Do it@", user_path(@user), :class => "btn icon-ok icon-white" %>
```

Comment: @PeterNixey no it does not, it makes it look like a button.  If you leave of the `btn` class, all you see is the icon.  The button look doesn't mean it's a button.

Answer (score 7):

Using HAML:

```
= link_to model_path do
  %img{src: '/assets/someimg.png'}
```

Answer (score 6):

In the gem twitter-bootstrap-rail : they create a helper glyph

```
  def glyph(*names)
    content_tag :i, nil, :class => names.map{|name| "icon-#{name.to_s.gsub('_','-')}" }
  end
```

So you can use it like: `glyph(:twitter)`
and you link helper could look like: `link_to glyph(:twitter),  user_path(@user)`

Comment: you could allow multiple clases for the a tag... In all cases, wich will be the use cases?

Comment: This is a great way to create a link with a glyph (Font Awesome)! To add more classes use something like `<%= link_to glyph(:comments), post_path(post), :class => "btn-small btn-warning" %>`. Here `comments` is the name of the Font Awesome character, `post_path(post)` is the destination url and `class =>` shows which classes the glyph will use.

Answer (score 3):

I will give this a shot since you haven't accepted an answer yet
and the other answers are not 100% what you were looking for.
This is the way to do it the Rails way.

```
<%= link_to(user_path(@user), :class => 'btn') do %>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-white"> </i> Do it!
<% end %>
```

Edit: leaving my answer for future reference,
but @justin-herrick has the correct answer when
working with Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplified it through a helper method if you use it frequently in your application.

put it in helper/application_helper.rb

```
def show_link(link_text, link_source)
  link_to("#{content_tag :i, nil, class: 'icon-ok icon-white'} #{link_text}".html_safe,
    link_source, class: "btn")
end
```

Then call it from your view file just like link_to

```
<%= show_link "Do it", user_path(@user) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the bootstrap 3.2.0, you can use this helper in your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def glyph(*names)
    content_tag :i, nil, :class => names.map{|name| "glyphicon glyphicon-#{name.to_s.gsub('_','-')}" }
  end
end
```

and then, in your views:

```
link_to glyph(:pencil) + ' Edit', edit_post_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def show_link (source, text)
  link_to source, {'data-original-title' => 'Show', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success'} do
    "#{text} #{content_tag :i, nil, class:' glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open' }".html_safe
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Helper based on Titas Milan's suggestion, but using a block:

```
def show_link(link_text, link_source)
  link_to link_source, { class: 'btn' } do
    "#{content_tag :i, nil, class: 'icon-ok icon-white'} #{link_text}".html_safe
  end
end
```