# Embed additional HTML inside of link_to call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I embed additional HTML inside of a link_to call?

Here is my desired result:

```
<a href="/exercies/show/1"><i class="icon-show"></i>Show</a>
```

Here is my link_to call

```
<%= link_to "Show", exercise_path(exercise) %>
```

Comment: I answered this just earlier today! Check out this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401942/using-link-to-with-embedded-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= link_to '<i class="icon-search"></i> Show'.html_safe, exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>
```

.html_safe is required so that it is not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It is cleaner if you wrap it in a do block

`<%= link_to exercise_path(exercise) do %>
  <i class="icon-search"></i> Show
<% end %>`