# Ruby on Rails - embed additional HTML inside of link_to call that includes I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, icons, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to embed additional HTML inside of a link_to call as found in this thread [Embed additional HTML inside of link_to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403256/embed-additional-html-inside-of-link-to-call)

However, I would also like to use I18n. So instead of this:

```
 <%= link_to '<i class="icon-search"></i> Show'.html_safe, exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>
```

I would like to use `t(:show)` or `I18n.t(:show)` instead of a hardcoded `Show` in the above example. I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax, though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an easier/cleaner way to embed additional items into a `link_to` by using its block syntax.  E.x.

```
<%= link_to exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' do %>
  <i class="icon-search"></i>
  <%= t(:show).html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "<i class='icon-search'></i> #{t(:show)}".html_safe, exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>`

Use `#{}` to embed ruby code in strings.

Comment: Thank you, but when I use double quotes as in your answer I get a syntax error, and if I use single quotes with `<%= link_to '<i class="icon-search"></i> #{t(:show)}'.html_safe, exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>`, the embedded ruby doesn't work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, for my solution to work, you would have needed to do `class='icon-search'` with single quotes. But johnernaut's answer is better anyway ;) I don't think you need the html_safe in his answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Use raw function just like below example

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class='icon-search'>some italic text </i> #{t(:show)}"), exercise_path(exercise), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>
```