# Converting to embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, embedded-ruby

How would I go about converting:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
```

to embedded ruby? Right now I have the following working, but I don't know how to add the i class, which is leaving the button looking funky.

```
 <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: "btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"  %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - embed additional HTML inside of link\_to call that includes I18n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977715/ruby-on-rails-embed-additional-html-inside-of-link-to-call-that-includes-i18n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
<%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: "btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
<% end %>
```