# How to make CSS apply to only a portion of the link_to text?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, link-to

A) This is the working link:

```
<%= link_to "+ Start a club", account_setup_path(id: :start_a_club) %>
```

B) This is what I want it to look like:

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw hot-pink"></i>&nbsp; Start a club</a>
```

How do I re-write A to get the correct CSS (ie. so the '+' is hot-pink)?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed additional HTML inside of link\_to call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403256/embed-additional-html-inside-of-link-to-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to account_setup_path(id: :start_a_club), class: 'list-group-item' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw hot-pink"></i>&nbsp; Start a club
<% end %>
```