# How do I use a twitter bootstrap icon instead of a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, icons, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to use Twitter Bootstrap Icons as Links in Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764862/best-way-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-icons-as-links-in-ruby-on-rails-3)

I have the following code to delete an item:

```
    <%= link_to "delete", sense,   :method => :delete,
                                   :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

How do I attach :method and :confirm to the `icon-remove` used in boostrap. I want something like:

```
    <%= link_to <i class="icon-search"></i>, sense,   :method => :delete,
                                                      :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= link_to sense, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" do %>
  <i class="icon-search"></i>
<% end %>
```

This should do it.