# adding html to link_to

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, actionview

how can I add the following html into my link_to

```
<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>

<%= link_to 'add', '#', :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right'%></th>
```

so that the html that will be produced will look like this

```
<a class="btn btn-mini pull-right" href="#">
<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401942/using-link-to-with-embedded-html/9401988#9401988), where I answer pretty much this exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to/) for more info, but you have two main options. I prefer the second option, but it's up to you!

1. Inline it.

   ```
   <%= link_to '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>', '#', :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right'%>
   ```
2. Put it in a block.

   ```
   <%= link_to(@user) do %>
     <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
   <% end %>
   ```